# without creation of object how enums are working in C

Tags: enums

How enums are working without creation of object.

```
    typedef enum
{
    a=0,b,c;
}Sample_Enum;



int main()
{
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Output Ans: 0

Answer (score 0):

`Enum`s do not require initialization to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In C enums are special kinds of integers. You can implicitly cast them from and to integers and `a` here is but an integer constant.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, one doubt suppose i was declared my enum in my .h file and directly i was used "a variable" in .c file, in that case how enum is working without creation of object.

Comment: @Lingesh: `a`,`b`,`c` are const enum objects (actually, just const integers). They don't need to be created again.